# cannot type filter text in eclipse toggle breadcrumb

Tags: eclipse, breadcrumbs

How can I **type filter text** in toggle breadcrumb like in this picture?

[image: illustration of problem]

I can not type text in 3.4 (Ganymede), Indigo Helios and 4.2 Release (Juno Packages).

**Alternatively**, is there any plugin to toggle the filtering of breadcrumb?

ps: The picture is from [one page](http://blog.csdn.net/xiao_jiang51/article/details/2211760) introducing whats new of eclipse 3.4 M5 
**but** I can not find the "type filter text" in [whats new of eclipse  3.4 realease](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news-part2.html)